# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isd_code' of null

Tags: angular, formbuilder

### Component.ts

```
@Input() userProfile: any;
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {}
ngOnInit() {
this.profile = this.formBuilder.group({
gender: [this.userProfile.gender],
      first_name: [this.userProfile.first_name, Validators.required],
      last_name: [this.userProfile.last_name, Validators.required],
      isd_code: [this.userProfile.phone_number.isd_code],
      phone_number: [this.userProfile.phone_number.phone_number],
})
}
```

Here in `userProfile` the `phone_number` and child `phone_number` and `isd_code` are not available initially. So when I try to edit the profile page I'm getting the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isd_code' of null
>           at profileEditComponent.ngOnInit

In html I use the safe navigation operator but here I have to set the values in `formbuilder` otherwise the validation fails even if the value is set.

I tried to check if the property is undefined but it doesn't work `this.userProfile.phone_number.isd_code != undefined`.

Comment: Can you do 
`[this.userProfile.phone_number && this.userProfile.phone_number.isd_code || null]`

Comment: @callback No, that doesn't solve the issue

Comment: But your check `this.userProfile.phone_number.isd_code != undefined` will fail in the same place as the formBuilder - if `phone_number` is undefined/null. You have no problem of undefined `isd_code`, you have a problem of the object one step higher.

Comment: you can simply console.log(this.userProfile) on top of ngOnInit and see if isd_code exists

Comment: "Here in userProfile the phone_number and child phone_number and isd_code are not available initially" - then I see another problem on the horizon: you should handle the input changes not in `ngOnInit` (which is fired once and won't be again), but in `ngOnChanges`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use safe navigation operator **`?`** or ternary operator for typescript

Try like this:

```
this.userProfile?.phone_number?.isd_code != undefined
```

In TS:

```
isd_code: [(this.userProfile)?(this.userProfile.phone_number ? this.userProfile.phone_number.isd_code : null) : null],
```

Comment: This operator is available in templates, not in the TS.

Comment: @Adrita Sharma As i have mentioned in my question it doesn't work in TS

Comment: @AdritaSharma This doesn't work if the phone_number is not set. Sorry for not mentioning in post. Will edit the post now

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case may be that the `this.userProfile.phone_number` has a value of **null** and you are trying to access a property of an element with **null** value. 
You should check the value of `this.userProfile.phone_number` before trying to access a property:

```
this.profile = this.formBuilder.group({
            gender: [this.userProfile.gender],
            first_name: [this.userProfile.first_name, Validators.required],
            last_name: [this.userProfile.last_name, Validators.required],
            isd_code: [this.userProfile.phone_number ? this.userProfile.phone_number.isd_code : ''],
            phone_number: [this.userProfile.phone_number ? this.userProfile.phone_number.phone_number : '']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not initialize it with empty object.

```
@Input() userProfile: any= new UserProfile();
```

And in UserProfile make sure you have intizalized the phone_number with empty object .

Comment: Will this work if I have already created a model for userProfile

Comment: if you have already created a model with some prepopulated values, use that model to assign to your userprofile ,make sure you have the fields initialized to some values .

Answer (score 0):

It's an API problem.

Steps:

1. Check all datatypes of the value,
2. Check getting null to any value,
3. Check controller in the API

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).